# How to convert vtk file to 3D data set?

Tags: python, vtk

I have a vtk file outputted from a program, and what I require is a 3D data set. This vtk file is an ROI which I drew in another program, and I would like to convert it into a mask of the ROI (i.e., 1s where the ROI is, 0 everywhere else). It should be of the same size as the original 3D image which had the ROI drawn on top of it. I'm working in Python. Does anyone know how I can convert this vtk file into essentially a 3D numpy array?

Comment: does [this](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Wrapping/Python/vtkmodules/util/numpy_support.py) help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that converts a VTK to a Numpy array for SimpleITK.

You can use this blog/documentation website for VTK examples: https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/

```
import numpy as np 
import SimpleITK as sitk 
import vtk  
from vtk.util import numpy_support 

def vtk2stik(self, polydata, spacing, inval=1, outval=0, cast_float32=True):

    # compute dimensions
    bounds = polydata.GetBounds()
    dim = [0] * 3
    for i in range(3):
        dim[i] = int(math.ceil((bounds[i * 2 + 1] - bounds[i * 2]) / spacing[i])) + 1
        if dim[i] < 1:
            dim[i] = 1

    origin = [0] * 3
    # NOTE: I am not sure whether or not we had to add some offset!
    origin[0] = bounds[0]  # + spacing[0] / 2
    origin[1] = bounds[2]  # + spacing[1] / 2
    origin[2] = bounds[4]  # + spacing[2] / 2

    # Convert the VTK array to vtkImageData
    whiteImage = vtk.vtkImageData()
    whiteImage.SetDimensions(dim)
    whiteImage.SetExtent(0, dim[0] - 1, 0, dim[1] - 1, 0, dim[2] - 1)
    whiteImage.SetSpacing(spacing)
    whiteImage.SetOrigin(origin)
    whiteImage.GetPointData()
    whiteImage.AllocateScalars(vtk.VTK_UNSIGNED_CHAR, 1)

    # fill the image with foreground voxels:
    count = whiteImage.GetNumberOfPoints()
    for i in range(count):
        whiteImage.GetPointData().GetScalars().SetTuple1(i, inval)

    # polygonal data -. image stencil:
    pol2stenc = vtk.vtkPolyDataToImageStencil()
    pol2stenc.SetTolerance(0)  # important if extruder.SetVector(0, 0, 1) !!!
    pol2stenc.SetInputData(polydata)
    pol2stenc.SetOutputOrigin(origin)
    pol2stenc.SetOutputSpacing(spacing)
    pol2stenc.SetOutputWholeExtent(whiteImage.GetExtent())
    pol2stenc.Update()

    # cut the corresponding white image and set the background:
    imgstenc = vtk.vtkImageStencil()
    imgstenc.SetInputData(whiteImage)
    imgstenc.SetStencilConnection(pol2stenc.GetOutputPort())
    imgstenc.ReverseStencilOff()
    imgstenc.SetBackgroundValue(outval)
    imgstenc.Update()

    # imgstenc.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetArray(0)
    np_array = numpy_support.vtk_to_numpy(imgstenc.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetScalars())
    sitk_img = sitk.GetImageFromArray(np_array.reshape(dim[2], dim[1], dim[0]))  # reversed dimension here
    sitk_img.SetSpacing(spacing)
    sitk_img.SetOrigin(origin)

    if cast_float32:
        cast_filter = sitk.CastImageFilter()
        cast_filter.SetNumberOfThreads(0)
        cast_filter.SetOutputPixelType(sitk.sitkFloat32)
        sitk_img = cast_filter.Execute(sitk_img)

    return sitk_img
```

Comment: Dear sir, thank you very much for this code. This is almost what I need. What I forgot to specify was that the number of ROIs is >1. For example if there were 2 ROIs I should either get two numpy arrays or a numpy array that contains values of 0 for background, 1 for ROI1 and 2 for ROI2. Do you know where this is saved in the .vtk file? I know it must be in there as the program I used to draw the ROIs is able to load in these vtk files, but I am not sure. Thank you very much for your helps.

Comment: If you have multiple labels in your VTK file, you can use the VTK filter called "vtkPolyDataConnectivityFilter":

See examples here: https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Python/Filtering/ConnectivityFilter/

This will extract the different component, you can create one polydata per component, and convert each component to a binary mask/numpy.